# Unit testing in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hey - I'm new to python , and I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of Unit testing in python.

I'm coming from Java - so unit testing makes sense because - well , there you actually have a unit - A Class. But a Python class is not necessarily the same as a Java class , and the way I use Python - as a scripting language - is more functional then OOP - So what do you "unit test" in Python ? A flow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is a script not a unit?  I don't get the distinction you're making.   Can you explain why a script is not a unit?

Comment: Python CAN be Object Oriented, nothing about the language makes it a functional language except the author.  To say otherwise, is incorrect

Answer (score 9):

Python has a [unit test module](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) that I like. You can also read [unit test section](http://www.diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html) of Dive Into Python.

Heres a basic example from the (linked) documentation:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Apparently http://diveintopython.org/ is gone/down?

Comment: Indeed it is, ill remove the link.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's not gone, it's just at http://diveintopython.net (or http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/ for python 3).

Comment: @max thanks, I've readded the link.

Answer (score 5):

If you make functional programming then the unit is the function and I would recommend to unit test your functions

Answer (score 5):

For quick and simple testing, you might like to have a look at [doctests](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html).

To write the tests, you place things that look like interactive interpreter sessions in a docstring:

```
def my_function(n):
    """Return n + 5

    >>> my_function(500)
    505"""
    return n + 5
```

to run the test, you import `doctest` and run `doctest.testmod()` which will run all the doctests in the module. You can also use `doctest.testfile("...")` to run all the tests in some other file.

If you check the [documentation for doctests](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) you will find ways to make a test expect exceptions, lists, etc -- anything the interpreter would output, plus some wildcards for brevity.

This is a quick way to write tests in Python modules, there isn't a lot of boilerplate code, and IMO it's easier to keep them up to date (the test is right there in the function!). But I also find them a little ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a post about [unit testing in IronPython](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2009/05/20/getting-started-with-ironpython-part-3-unit-testing.aspx) - it works same as in other Python flavors as well.

Have a look at these projects as well:

- [unittest — Unit testing framework](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)
- [python-nose - Test discovery tool](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/)